# What happens to form / JavaScript data when browser window is closed?

Tags: javascript, security, memory, browser

I have a html form which collects data in input elements and then generates a PDF (using jsPDF) for the user to download (using Downloadify js).  The data collected contains personal information.

What I need to know is will the data entered into the input elements, which then gets processed by JavaScript, remain in browser memory when the user navigates elsewhere or closes the browser window?

Comment: It won't save in a cache for you, best approach using pure client-side is to save in cookies or sessionStorage/localStorage (if supporting latest browsers)

Comment: I guess jwhd does not want it to be kept.

Comment: Thanks. Yes Ali, my preference would be to not have this sensitive information stored/cached in browser memory (by JS) when the user closes the window.  This is specifically what I need to understand.  I'm aware, as the answer below by Dheeraj suggests, that form input data may be retrieved using the autocomplete feature on browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will probably remain in memory for a period. This is beyond you control, and will differ between browsers and operating systems.

If your form is not actually submitted to the server, autocomplete should not store it, although you may want to add `autocomplete="off"` to be extra sure of this.

You could also use JavaScript to set the form values to blank once processing is done.

```
document.getElementById('name').value = '';
```

You could also set any JavaScript objects to null after use. This will not guarantee that the data would not be held in memory somewhere. You could encourage users to close all browser windows after use and logout of the operating system if this is a concern. Browsers such as Chrome can remain in memory even though all windows are closed as it can live in the system tray if that option is set so logging out will force it to close whilst being easy for users to do.

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much confirmed what I thought might be the case

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The form data is saved in browser memory even if the user navigates to other page or closes the tab. It will saved in temporary browser auto-fill cache. You can disable this by using the attribute `autocomplete="off"` for form elements.

You can find more about autocomplete attribute here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Answer (score 0):

1. Set autocomplete off. Auto fill will not save if this Is set.
2. Set Cache Headers in the response to not cache. Browser will not cache the page and discard when closed.